# Reemplazar Controles entre paneles

Tags: vb.net

En el formulario hay como un tablero de ajedrez hecho con paneles.
En unos cuantos de esos paneles hay un Label en cada uno.
Necesito, que al mover uno de esos Label a otro panel que ya contiene un Label, este último se ingrese en el panel del que estoy arrastrando para poder soltarlo en el nuevo Panel.
Por ahora, solo puedo mover los Label a paneles vacíos.
Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el de DragDrop.

Muchas gracias.

Edito: He probado con FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel y funciona pero me surgen otros problema. Por lo que he tenido que desecharlos.

Edito:

```
Dim btname, tbindx As Integer
Private Sub ParaForo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        tbindx += 1
        btname += 1
        Btletras = New Label
        'Btletras.AllowDrop = True
        Btletras.Name = "L" & btname
        Btletras.Text = Btletras.Name
        Btletras.Margin = New Padding(0)
        Btletras.TabIndex = tbindx
        Btletras.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        Btletras.Size = New Size(30, 30)
        Btletras.Margin = New Padding(0)
        Btletras.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
        Btletras.Parent = PnlLetras
        PnlLetras.Controls.Add(Btletras)

        AddHandler Btletras.MouseDown, AddressOf OnButtonMouseDown1
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub PnlsDragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles _
    Pnl11.DragOver, Pnl12.DragOver, Pnl21.DragOver, Pnl22.DragOver, PnlLetras.DragOver

    If e.AllowedEffect = DragDropEffects.Move AndAlso e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Label)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
    End If
End Sub

Sub PnlsDragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles _
    Pnl11.DragDrop, Pnl12.DragDrop, Pnl21.DragDrop, Pnl22.DragDrop, PnlLetras.DragDrop

    Dim btltrs = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(Label)), Label)
    Dim destPanel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

   If destPanel.Controls.Count <= 0 Then destPanel.Controls.Add(btltrs)
    'destPanel.Enabled = False ' No eliminar
End Sub

Private DragDropCursor As Cursor
Private Sub Pnls_Feedback1(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles _
    Pnl11.GiveFeedback, Pnl12.GiveFeedback, Pnl21.GiveFeedback, Pnl22.GiveFeedback, PnlLetras.GiveFeedback

    e.UseDefaultCursors = False
    Cursor.Current = DragDropCursor

End Sub
WithEvents Btletras As Control
Dim btindex As String
Private Sub OnButtonMouseDown1(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim btltrs = DirectCast(sender, Label)

    Using bmp As New Bitmap(btltrs.Width, btltrs.Height)
        btltrs.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, Btletras.Size))
        DragDropCursor = New Cursor(bmp.GetHicon)
    End Using
    Btletras.Parent.DoDragDrop(btltrs, DragDropEffects.Move)

    btindex = btltrs.Name
    If PnlLetras.Controls.Find(btindex, True).Length = 0 Then
        If btltrs.Name = btindex Then
            'btltrs.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Si el label ocupa todo el panel, tu dragdrop no se va a ejecutar porque no va contra el panel, si no contra el label... mas alla de eso, no termino de entender tu codigo...

Comment: Yo creo que el problema está en la línea:    'If destPanel.Controls.Count <= 0 Then destPanel.Controls.Add(btltrs)' Y es desde ahí, desde donde se puede solucionar. Tendría que ser averiguando el name de ese panel para mover el control que contiene al panel de la derecha. El problema esta en que con el cursor pillado arrastrando un control, no se como provocar un evento MouseEnter o algo así

Comment: Creo que con el evento DragOver si que se puede provocar.